# Data transformation trom value to keyword

Tags: clojure

Say I have the following data:

```
({:year 2023, :month 4, :type TypeA, :cat CatA, :amount 62.5} 
 {:year 2023, :month 4, :type TypeB, :cat CatB, :amount 45.25} 
 {:year 2023, :month 4, :type TypeC, :cat CatA, :amount 40.0} 
 {:year 2023, :month 5, :type TypeA, :cat CatA, :amount 52.75} 
 {:year 2023, :month 5, :type TypeC, :cat CatA, :amount 14.0})
```

I would like to transform this by type or by cat into the following:

```
({:year 2023, :month 4, :typeA 62.5, :typeB 42.25, :typeC 40.0}
 {:year 2023, :month 5, :typeA 52.75, :typeB 0, :typeC 14.0}}
```

or the same by cat:

```
({:year 2023, :month 4, :catA 102.5, :catB 42.25}
 {:year 2023, :month 5, :catA 52.75, :catB 14.0}}
```

I sorta tried it with distinct and nested maps but have not found a valid solution.

BONUS:
The types and cats should be flexible and it is not safe to reference them by name hard-coded.

Comment: You're gonna love `clojure.core/group-by`.

Comment: hm, but then how to accumulate all groups (say cats or types) in one map?

Comment: Data in your question are inconsistent- `45.25` vs `42.25`; there is `:catB 14.0` in the result, but `:cat CatA, :amount 14.0` in the data. And `102.5` is probably the sum of `62.5` and `40.0`- this summation isn't included in Eugene Pakhomov's answer.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @MartinPůda You are totally correct. I added a group-by beforehand and everything is fine.

Comment: > how to accumulate all groups (say cats or types) in one map? --- a typical way to go from a sequence to a single item in Clojure is `clojure.core/reduce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result seems to be close enough.

```
(let [data '({:year 2023, :month 4, :type TypeA, :cat CatA, :amount 62.5}
             {:year 2023, :month 4, :type TypeB, :cat CatB, :amount 45.25}
             {:year 2023, :month 4, :type TypeC, :cat CatA, :amount 40.0}
             {:year 2023, :month 5, :type TypeA, :cat CatA, :amount 52.75}
             {:year 2023, :month 5, :type TypeC, :cat CatA, :amount 14.0})
      key-fields [:year :month]
      k-field :cat
      ;k-field :type
      v-field :amount]
  (->> data
       (group-by #(select-keys % key-fields))
       (mapv (fn [[k ms]]
               (reduce (fn [k m]
                         (let [;; Not sure if you need to make the first character lower-case here.
                               f (keyword (k-field m))]
                           (assoc k f (v-field m))))
                       k ms)))))
```

It doesn't add zeros for absent values, but I'd argue that it's usually best not to add them. Instead, the clients of this code can decide what to do with them.

Answer (score 3):

also, the one pass (and a bit simpler option, i guess):

```clj
(defn process [k data]
  (vals (reduce 
         #(let [y-m (select-keys %2 [:year :month])]
            (update % y-m (fnil assoc y-m) (keyword (k %2)) (:amount %2)))
         nil 
         data)))
```

```clj
user> (process :type data)
;;=> ({:year 2023, :month 4, :TypeA 62.5, :TypeB 45.25, :TypeC 40.0}
;;   {:year 2023, :month 5, :TypeA 52.75, :TypeC 14.0})

user> (process :cat data)
;;=> ({:year 2023, :month 4, :CatA 40.0, :CatB 45.25}
;;    {:year 2023, :month 5, :CatA 14.0})
```

Answer (score 0):

The same, but with transducers:

```
(defn transform [key]
    (xf/into-by-key [] (fn-> (select-keys [:year :month])) identity into
        (xf/into-by-key [] (fn-> key keyword) :amount vector (xf/reduce +))))

(into [] (xf/transjuxt {:type (transform :type)
                        :cat  (transform :cat)}) data)
=>
[{:type 
       [{:year 2023, :month 4, :TypeA 62.5, :TypeB 45.25, :TypeC 40.0}
         {:year 2023, :month 5, :TypeA 52.75, :TypeC 14.0}],
  :cat 
       [{:year 2023, :month 4, :CatA 102.5, :CatB 45.25} 
        {:year 2023, :month 5, :CatA 66.75}]}]
```

`xf` being `[net.cgrand.xforms :as xf]`